# PropertyReferenceException:Spring Data JPA error No property found for type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-11, spring-mybatis

I am working on an upgrade of a spring boot application from JDK 1.8 to 11 and moving to Spring boot version: 2.4.9 from 2.0.3.RELEASE.

Application build is successful but the application is failing to run due to the following exception. Please note that this application is running successfully on JDK 1.8 and Spring boot version:2.0.3.RELEASE.

Can you please help me here?

> Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseServiceController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'posPdmOperationServiceImpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'posPdmOperationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionBusinessService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionBusinessServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'populateRptTablesService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'populateRptTablesServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storedProcedureRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storedProcedureRepo' defined in com.client.databaseservice.repositories.StoredProcedureRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on OracleDbConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract boolean com.client.databaseservice.rptmaster.repository.OracleTypeRepository.insertStrOpenDataForRebellion(java.util.List,java.util.List)! No property insertStrOpenDataForRebellion found for type StoredProcedureModel!
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property insertStrOpenDataForRebellion found for type StoredProcedureModel!

Attaching each file mentioned in the error trace below:

OracleDbConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "oracleEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "oracleTransactionManager", basePackages = "com.client.databaseservice.repositories")
public class OracleDbConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.oracle.datasource")
    public DataSource postgresqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "oracleEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(postgresqlDataSource()).properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages("com.client.databaseservice.transaction.models").persistenceUnit("oraclePU").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "oracleTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager postgresqlTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("oracleEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    private Map hibernateProperties() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);

            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), e -> e.getValue()));
    }
}
```

**OracleTypeRepositoryImpl**

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oracleEntityManager")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public boolean insertStrOpenDataForRebellion(List<RPTMasterData> rptMasterDataArrayList,
            List<RPTTenderData> rptTenderDataArrayList) {

        final String sql = "{call REBELLION_STORE_OPERATIONS.ADDSTROPENREBELLIONDATA(?,?,?)}";
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        boolean result = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Boolean>() {//Logic to call procedure});
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this line `ArrayList<RPTMasterData> masterData = //logic` ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス Updated the corresponding code section. Please check.